# How can I make a unit test for python telegram bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm currently using [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) for create telegram bot. But every change I made, I have to do feature test by my hands. How can I create a unit test for a telegram bot using a tool such as `pytest` or `unittest`?

Is there a way to generate the same traffic without telegram or control telegram in a terminal environment for test my telegram bot?

Using python3, the latest version of `python-telegram-bot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to create JSON with real data from user. Then use `requests` to send a test messages to the your server endpoint.
To get a valid JSON data you can save `update` object.

Comment: Since I used the module (python-telegram-bot) instead of HTTP endpoint method, I couldn't inject my json request. Do you have any idea for this problem?

Comment: you can use `telethon`